# Proof that a certain condition is equivalent to convergence of a real sequence

Tags: real-analysis

Show that Definition $2.6$ is equivalent to the following slight modification:
We write $\lim_{n \to \infty} s_n = L$ provided that for every positive integer $m$ there is a real number $N$ so that $|s_n − L| <\frac 1 m$ whenever $n \ge N$.

Definition $2.6$ says: (Limit of a Sequence) Let $(s_n)_{n\in \Bbb{N}}$ be a sequence of real numbers. We say that $(s_n)_{n\in \Bbb{N}}$ converges to a number $L$ and write
$\lim_{n \to \infty} s_n = L$  or    $s_n \to L$ as $n \to \infty$
provided that for every number $\varepsilon > 0$ there is an integer $N$ so that
$|s_n − L| < \varepsilon$ whenever $n \ge N$.

What I have so far is: By choosing a $M$ that is very large so that $\frac 1 m$ is similar to $\varepsilon$.
$|s_n − L| <\frac 1 m $
then we have $L-\frac 1 m < s_n < L+\frac 1 m$.
And here is where I draw a blank. To show they are equivalant I set them equal to show epsilon equals $\frac 1 m$?

Answer (score 1):

The real $N$ versus natural $N$ is a silly matter easily disposed of using the Archimedean property. I call it silly because it's only a slight convenience to allow it to be real, and doing so breaks the proper mental model. The $\epsilon$ vs. $1/n$ thing is much more productive to think about: it should lead you naturally the the concept of a "neighborhood base" (also called a local base, or a neighborhood basis, or a local basis, or a base for a neighborhood system, etc.), which is fairly important. It also leads to the notion of "first countable". So pay close attention to that aspect of it.

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea:

If a sequence converges by Def. 2.6, it converges by the modified definition just by taking $\epsilon=1/m$.

Now suppose a sequence converges to L by the modified definition.  To show that it converges to L by Def. 2.6, given an $\epsilon>0$, choose a positive integer $m$ with $m>\frac{1}{\epsilon}$, so then $1/m<\epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

to show that both, definition 2.6 and its modification, is equivalent, you have to show that any sequence which converges in the sense of 2.6 also converge in the sense of the modification and vice versa. 
Let $(s_n)$ be a sequence converging to $L$ (assume first that this convergence is meant in the sense of 2.6). You have to show that for each $m\in\mathbb N$ there is a real number N such that $|s_n-L|<\frac{1}{m}$ whenever $n\geq N$. We know that 2.6 is true, that is, for each $\epsilon>0$ there is a natural number $N'$ such that $|s_n-L|<\epsilon$ whenever $n\geq N'$. Can you continue?